# Which type of nut can be used as a replacement for the Dewalt router DC600B to securely hold a 1/2-inch shank?

Tags: routers

I own a Dewalt 20V Cordless Router DC600B equipped with a 1/4-inch nut. Can this be replaced with a specific type of 1/2-inch nut or collet that accommodates a 1/2-inch shank?

Comment: There may be 1/2" replacements out there, but the manual clearly states: *Always use cutters with a shank diameter of 1/4" (6.4 mm) which corresponds to the size of the collet in your tool.*

Comment: Unless your router explicitly has a 1/2" collet available, you're risking the bit coming loose and a large, sharp, fast moving hunk of metal flying out of it when you least expect it. If [DeWalt](https://dewalt.com) doesn't explicitly offer a 1/2" collet for this router, your answer is **NO** you cannot use 1/2" bits in this router.

Comment: The Necessary Components: **A router actually designed for a 1/2" shank.**

Comment: Or a bit with a 1/4" shank. Any bit small enough that it can be handled by that router *will* be available in both 1/4" and 1/2" shank sizes. Or, if it's a complicated profile, you may be able to cut the desired shape with a series of smaller bits. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>*Note: I don't think this question deserves an answer because it's a shopping question. **However**, this is a significant **safety** issue that should be addressed.
The shopping aspects have been edited out after the question was closed, but this is still a significant safety issue.*</sup>

The [DeWalt info page](https://www.dewalt.com/product/dcw600b/20v-max-xr-brushless-cordless-compact-router) for the DCW600 says `Diameter 6.35 mm` which is 1/4". Therefore NO you cannot use it for 1/2" shank bits.

For comparison, the [DW618 router specs](https://www.dewalt.com/product/dw618/2-14-hp-maximum-motor-hp-evs-fixed-base-router-soft-start?tid=597016) say it includes `1/4" and 1/2" Collets`, therefore this one is designed for either.

Attempting to put a 1/2" shank bit into your 1/4" collet router

1. probably won't work at all

   1. Not sure how you're going to get a 1/2" diameter steel shank into a 1/4" hole (in the router's drive shaft), collet nut size is irrelevant here.
2. if you, somehow, managed to shoehorn it in:

   1. it would be exceedingly dangerous
   2. the router might not be able to spin the bit once it hits wood, as 1/2" shanks are usually used for larger diameter bits that take more HP to spin & cut. Of course, small bits (like a 1/4" flush trim bit) are available with a 1/2" shank, but if that's what you need to use, buy one with a 1/4" shank suitable for this router.

Notes:

- I happen to own both of these DeWalt routers. I would *NEVER* even consider trying to jam a 1/2" shank into the cordless router. They're both excellent *for their designed purposes*. Don't try to force a power tool beyond its designed limitations - that's how emergency room visits start.
- If you *really* want a 1/2" collet on a cordless router, I hear Milwaukee is about to or has just released an M18 powered, 2.25HP 1/4" & 1/2" router.

Comment: A router is a high RPM device, and you definitely don't want to be screwing around with unofficial adapters and what not. Anything coming at you from a machine that generates thousands of RPM is going to hurt/kill you for sure.

Comment: A router can be spinning at 30,000 RPM, which I think translates to a linear speed of well over 200 MPH at the cutting edge of a 1/2" radius bit. A 22 caliber bullet is only about 3x that. This is not something you want to risk coming loose. There are some weird and wonderful widgets that can be attached to routers, but do not attempt to cheat.

Comment: Huh. A down vote? Does someone actually think that attempting to put a 1/2" diameter piece of steel into a 1/4" diameter hole is A) possible, or B) a good idea? I know an explanation isn't required, but it sure does help...